# HTTP Request extreme slow on a Samsung Tab A with Android 5.0.2

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, httpurlconnection

I have an app, which makes lots of downloads using `HttpURLConnection` in different threads. The first activity makes 2 threaded requests during `onCreate`. All works fine on several devices, but now my customer (!) bought a Samsung Tab A SM-T550 with Android 5.0.2.
On this tablet, my app needs minutes for every request, whereas the other devices are need just a second. The customer told me, that the time is wasted until the request reaches the server. (Based on timestamps in the logfile)

Other apps are working well, so my customer blames me for this issue.

Are there any known problems with this device or Android version?

UPDATE:
I got the tablet from my customer today, connected it to my WLAN and it worked well!
But in his office I could see by myself, that the connection was extremely slow, whereas other apps ran quickly.
How is that possible?
The customer has a very fast DSL connection. (50 or 100 MBit - he wasn't sure) 
It seems, as if the problem is locally, but I have no idea where to search for a solution...

Here is my code:

```
public boolean requestHTTPData(TransferResult txResult, String url) {
    boolean res = false;
    this.txResult = txResult;
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        txResult.setData(in);
        txResult.setResult(TransferResult.RESULT_OK);
        res = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        txResult.setError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here is the code from TranferResult:

```
public class TransferResult {
    public static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
    public static final int RESULT_ERROR = -1;
    public static final int RESULT_UNDEF = 0;

    protected String response = null;
    protected int result = RESULT_UNDEF;
    protected StringBuffer errorText = null;
    protected BufferedReader data = null;
    protected Boot[] boote;
    protected int startIndex = 0;
    protected int anzahl = 0;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public BufferedReader getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(BufferedReader data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public boolean wasSuccessfull() {
        return (result == RESULT_OK);
    }

    public Boot[] getBoote() {
        return boote;
    }
    public void setBoote(Boot[] boote) {
        this.boote = boote;
    }

    public int getStartIndex() {
        return startIndex;
    }
    public void setStartIndex(int startIndex) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
    }
    public int getAnzahl() {
        return anzahl;
    }
    public void setAnzahl(int anzahl) {
        this.anzahl = anzahl;
    }
    public void setError(String newErrorText) {
        if (newErrorText != null && newErrorText.length() > 0) {
            if (errorText == null) {
                errorText = new StringBuffer();
            } else {
                errorText.append("\n"); 
            }
            this.errorText.append(errorText);
        }
        result = RESULT_ERROR;
    }
    public StringBuffer getErrorText() {
        return errorText;
    }
    public void showError(Context context) {
        if (errorText == null) {
            setError("Errortext is NULL");
        }
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("");
        alertDialog.setMessage(errorText);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public TransferResult(Boot[] boote, int startIndex, int anzahl) {
        super ();
        this.setBoote(boote);
        this.setStartIndex(startIndex);
        this.setAnzahl(anzahl);
    }

    public TransferResult() {
        this (null, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: 'txResult.setData(in);' We cannot see if you are fiddling around there.

Comment: 'txResult.setResult(TransferResult.RESULT_OK);'. You are telling your self that all is ok. Even if things went wrong.

Comment: @greenapps: txResult.setData just stores the data for later use.

Comment: @greenapps: if something went wrong, I expect an exception and call txResult.setError, where setResult is set to RESULT_ERROR.

Comment: That is not correct.

Comment: I cannot see it. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Start with posting complete code. You were suggested to do so before.

Comment: If your customer uses WiFi it could be hardware issue. WiFi modules in Android devices use specific power save mode, which conflicts with some routers. Check if problem exists when you also downloading something large in background using tablet.